# nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "ssl_ciphers" directive in /etc/nginx/conf.d/todoproject.conf:42

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, error-handling, ssl-certificate

When I am trying to restart my nginx, I get:

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "ssl_ciphers" directive in /etc/nginx/conf.d/todoproject.conf:42
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

what I did so far...
`/etc/nginx/conf.d/todoproject.conf`

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name react-todo.cf;

  location / {
     proxy_pass http://3.18.184.211:5001/;
  }

  return 301 https://react-todo.cf;
}


# generated 2019-11-19, https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/#server=nginx&server-version=1.14.0&config=intermediate

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    server_name react-todo.cf;
    server_name react-todo.cf;

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://3.18.184.211:5001/;
    }

    # root /React-Redux-Todo-App/build;
    # certs sent to the client in SERVER HELLO are concatenated in ssl_certificate
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/jagan.cf/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/jagan.cf/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_session_cache shared:MozSSL:10m;  # about 40000 sessions
    ssl_session_tickets off;

    # curl https://ssl-config.mozilla.org/ffdhe2048.txt > /path/to/dhparam.pem
    # ssl_dhparam /path/to/dhparam.pem;

    # intermediate configuration
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305$
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # HSTS (ngx_http_headers_module is required) (63072000 seconds)
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000" always;

    # OCSP stapling
    # ssl_stapling on;
    # ssl_stapling_verify on;

    # verify chain of trust of OCSP response using Root CA and Intermediate certs
    # ssl_trusted_certificate /path/to/root_CA_cert_plus_intermediates;

    # replace with the IP address of your resolver
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
}
```

I am getting the error while running command

```
sudo nginx -t
```

or trying to restart nginx with command

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

This was my second app in same instance for which I was going to use ssl certificate.
first one was successfuly done but here in second one I'm getting this error.
my file is in directory
`/etc/nginx/conf.d/todoproject.conf`

Comment: try to add ";"   end of the ssl_ciphers line